# How to create an object for generic class?

Tags: java, class, object, generics, bounded-types

This is a generic class with bound type Player.

```
 public class Team<T extends Player> implements Comparable<Team<T>> {
    
        private String name;
        private int played=0;
        private int won=0;
        private int lost=0;
        private int tide=0;
    
        private ArrayList<T> members = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public Team(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public int getWon() {
            return won;
        }
    
        public boolean addPlayer(T player){
            if(members.contains(player)){
                System.out.println(player.getName() + " is already on this team" );
                return false;
            }else{
                members.add(player);
                System.out.println(player.getName()+" picked for team "+this.name);
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        public int numPlayer(){
            return this.members.size();
        }
    
     }
```

This is a generic class with bound Type as Team.

```
public class League<T extends Team>{
    public String name;
    private ArrayList<T> league = new ArrayList<>();

    public League(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean addTeam(T team){
        if(league.contains(team)){
            System.out.println("It is already exist");
            return false;
        }else{
            league.add(team);
            return true;
        }

    }

    public void showLeagueTable(){
        Collections.sort(league);
        for(T t:league){
            System.out.println(t.getName()+" : "+t.ranking());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to create an object for the League class, literally not able to figure out how to mention type. I've tried several ways, but none of them worked for me. Could you guys help me with this code?

Comment: `League<Team<Player>> league = new League<>("...");`

Comment: Fine, Could you pls explain the part "League<Team<Player>>"? Can't we just say League<Player>? I'm scratching my head. Pls, provide an explanation.

Comment: What ways did you try, and in what way did they not work?

Comment: The type parameter T in League says that T must extend Team. If you have a class Player which extends Team, you could say League<Player>. But you haven't shown your Player class.

Comment: Of course making Player extend Team is probably not what you want.